# is there any security issue that can be expected when the mqtt client doesn't provide public key certificate during TLS handshake?

Tags: authentication, ssl, client, mqtt, handshake

I am building up a small iot-like system, where mqtt devices(clients) are sending and receiving security-related critical information or commands.

I have got to know that TLS connection can be built optionally without client authentication thru PK certificate on the client side.

Normally, mqtt client devices don't have enough resources to support PKI, where at first it has to store a certificate and from time to time, to update it with newly issued ones when validity has passed or when the original certificate has been revoked.

That was, I think, why many of mqtt brokers have an option to configure on/off the client authentication during TLS handshake.

However, my concern is if there would be any security issue from passing the client authentication step, like, for example, a chance that some other malicious devices impersonating one of my devices can connect to the broker could obtain those critical information and commands.

My question is what best options and practices I can take to minimize that kind of risk considering the constraint resource of devices.

Answer (score 1):

Missing client authentication means that everybody including an attacker can claim to be a valid client. There can be use cases like public services where this is not a problem and there are other use cases where the server wants to restrict access to specific known clients only.

Comment: can you inform me about the public service that I can choose?

Comment: @BigSquare: I think you did not understand what I was trying to say. I'm not talking about a specific public service which you can choose but that in some cases the MQTT server does not care which client is connected (for example if the service is offered for arbitrary clients) while in other cases it is important that only authenticated clients can connect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer to this question, it will always depend on the following factors, and only you as the designer can answer them:

1. **What is the threat model you are working with?** E.g. Who are you trying to keep out of the system and why, what are the consequences of somebody connecting a rouge client?
2. **How much are you prepared to spend?** If you intend to deploy client certificate or even a unique username/password for each device, how will it be protected? Does the hardware you intend to use support a secure enclave/hardware secret store? Meaning how hard would it be for an attacker to extract the client username/password or secret key from the device?
3. **What other security measures do you have in place?** Do you have Access Control Lists to protect which topics a client can publish/subscribe to? Do you have monitoring in place to detect malicious actions from clients so they can be disconnected and banned?

Comment: well. you are asking too deep. Anyhow whatever security components an MCU may have, we cannot say it is safe. On that kind of profound basis, we cannot use MCU as a main system of MQTT client that is handling security-critical information.